# Cursor overwrites text in console application

Tags: c#

I am building an ascii version of TicTacToe as a class asigment and I ran into a problem.The cursor doverwrites the board and the signs.

```
 while (pressed == false)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            switch (cki.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if(sides+1>Console.WindowWidth)
                        break;
                    if(sides+1==17||sides+1==8)
                    sides+=2;
                else
                    sides += 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(sides, ver);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (sides - 1 < 0)
                        break;
                    if (sides -1 == 17 || sides -1 == 8)
                        sides -= 2;
                    else
                    sides -= 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(sides, ver);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    if (ver + 1 > Console.WindowHeight)
                        break;
                    if (ver+1==8||ver+1==17)
                        ver += 2;
                    else
                    ver += 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(sides, ver);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (ver - 1 < 0 )
                        break;
                    if (ver - 1 == 8 || ver - 1 == 17)
                    ver-=2;
                    else
                    ver -= 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(sides, ver);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.X:
                case ConsoleKey.O:                        
                    br.PutSign(ver,sides,ch);
                    pressed = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I fixed the problme that the cursor overwrites the board But I  still cant find a way to protect the sings(the X and the O)
Thats the board class for refernce:

```
public char[,] board = new char[27, 27];

public Board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (i==8||i==17)
                board[i, j] = '_';

            if (j==8||j==17)
                board[i, j] = '|';
        }
    }
}

public void PrintB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(board[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
public void PutSign(int row, int col, char ch)
{
    board[row, col] = ch;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD. CMD is a program, like yours.

Comment: Sorry my bad  should i change the tag  and the name into i "Console Apllication" ?

Comment: @hjsv41 what do you mean "protect" the strings?

Comment: Yep, it's using a console like all other console programs.

Comment: Whenever the user puts the cursor over the sign the char is overwritten by the cursor  and untill I print the board again the players cant see the sign(x or o).